# Detox Testing - How to disable detox info logging to stdout

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, detox

I've read through the docs and cannot find a way to set the log level to something like "silent". I don't want to see all the detox log info. I just want to see the test output. The current log levels are:

> -l, --loglevel [value]                      info, debug, verbose, silly, wss

Not specifying a log level defaults to info.

example:

[image: Detox testing output]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--loglevel` from you `detox test --loglevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are more options - `fatal, error, warn, info, verbose, trace` ([see docs](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DetoxCLI.md))

```
detox test --loglevel fatal
```

Results in clean test execution output:

[image]